# Why do the k-fold products of the germs of functions that vanish on a neighborhood of a point m form a descending sequence of ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-topology, ideals

I'm going through Warner's *Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups*, and he loves the idea of defining the tangent vectors at $p \in M$ using the germs of functions that agree on a neighborhood of $p$, which he denotes $\tilde{F}_p$.

He writes that the powers of the ideal formed by the germs which vanish in a neighborhood of $p$, denoted $F_p^k$ and representing the ideal formed  by the k-fold products of elements in $F_p$, form a descending sequence of ideals:

$$
\tilde{F}_p \supset F_p \supset F_p^2 \supset F_p^3 \supset \dots
$$

It's unclear to me why this claim is true. I need to understand this to make sense of the quotient he proposes afterward, namely $F_p / F_p^2$.

Could someone clarify?

Comment: It's not jut the powers, it's the ideal generated by them. The germs vanishing at $0$, $F_p$ if I interpret your notation correctly, form an ideal and $F_p^k$ is the $k$-fold product of $F_p$ with itself in the sense of ideals, i.e. the ideal consisting of linear combinations of products of $k$ elements from $F_p$.

Comment: Yes, sorry @Thorgott that was my meaning. Please feel free to modify the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reflection and discussion, it is now clear that Warner's statement is true in the sense that these spaces, $F_p^{j+1}$, represent those vanishing germs whose $j^{th}$ derivative vanishes at the point $p$. In that sense, it's clear that if the $(j-1)^{th}$ derivative vanishes, so does the $j^{th}$.

Answer (score 1):

If a germ belongs to $F_p^2$ then it is the product of two elements of $F_p$, so it still vanishes but up to "order 2". $F_p/F^2_p$ is just the germs that vanish modulo the germs which vanish "twice". So you get "differentials".

Comment: Thanks @nektarios I understand what he wants to say (you are essentially left with the linear functionals, $(F_p / F_p^2)^*$), but I can't see why they form the above-mentioned descending sequence of ideals.